Windows Shared Memory Access Issue Between Applications Running Under Different Sessions
Description
I am developing an Agent application that accesses shared memory across multiple applications. The setup involves three applications:
A: A WPF C# application.
B: A Python application is Agent.
C (BLauncher): A C# Windows Service that updates and restarts B if it is not running.
A: C#
public void UpdateInfo<T>(String fieldName, T info) where T : struct
{
    try
    {

        DataTag dataTag = new DataTag();
        _accessor.Read(0, out dataTag);


        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(DataTag).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (fieldInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Field '{fieldName}' does not exist in DataTag.");
        }


        if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(T))
        {
            fieldInfo.SetValueDirect(__makeref(dataTag), info);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Field '{fieldName}' is of type {fieldInfo.FieldType}, not {typeof(T)}.");
        }


        _accessor.Write(0, ref dataTag);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
    }
    
}

B: Python
    def connect(self):
    if self.shm is None:
        try:
            self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=self.memory_segment_name, create=False)
            logger.info(f"Successfully connected to shared memory segment: {self.memory_segment_name}")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            logger.error(f"Error: Shared memory segment '{self.memory_segment_name}' not found.")

            self.shm = None
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
            self.shm = None

Environment

PC1: My laptop running Windows 11 with a single user account. Shared memory access works correctly here.
PC2: A machine running Windows 10 with two user accounts: Hello and eHello. Shared memory issues occur on this machine.

Problem
On PC1 (single user account), application A writes ~2000 bytes of data to a shared memory segment named "MACHINE_INFO". Application B reads the data successfully when run as a Python script or as a standalone .exe.
However, on PC2 (with two user accounts), the following occurs:

Application C (a Windows Service running under the System account) starts B as an .exe.
B reports that the shared memory segment "MACHINE_INFO" does not exist.

Key Information

I suspect this might be related to how shared memory works across sessions in Windows. A prior discussion suggested that shared memory is session-specific, but I am unsure if that fully explains the issue.
C runs as a Windows Service under the System account.
Is it possible for a WPF application (A) to write to a shared memory segment that the System account (and therefore C) can access?

Questions

Does Windows handle shared memory in a session-specific way that could cause the "MACHINE_INFO" segment to be inaccessible across sessions?
How can I configure or implement shared memory so that it is accessible across all sessions, especially to applications running under the System account?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please share a [mcve].

@mjwills I added some codes.

That's not a [mcve].  Please read the link.

Where is the C# code that opens the shared memory?

The posted c# code just seem to be how you map memory to objects. And that is mostly irrelevant for the question you are posing. The important parts, i.e. how you setup the memory and how access is synchronized, is completely missing.

According to the documentation you should be able to specify a security descriptor when creating a memory mapping. But I'm not sure if all options are exposed in the c# API.

The WPF app would need to either run as admin, or the shared memory needs a security descriptor allowing access. Please show relevant C# code as asked.
